# How to find Best Match from the left in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose i have a list of string

```
DF01 
FR10
FR12 
RT10
FRFF
```

And i got number `FR10`.

I want the query to get `FR10` which is the best match from the left. Is there a query that can do that ??

I tried with query below but no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE str_col LIKE CONCAT('FR10', '%');
```

So how can i query to get results with following order (best match first).

```
FR10
FR12 
FRFF
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE str_col LIKE 'FR10%';` should work

Comment: what about order and it will not return FRFF,FR12

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE str_col LIKE 'FR%' ORDER BY str_col asc;` should work for ascending order.

Comment: FR10 donot get ordered according to match.... my current implementation is already using this approach but not return proper order by match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE str_col LIKE 'FR10%'
    OR str_col LIKE 'FR1%'
    OR str_col LIKE 'FR%'
    OR str_col LIKE 'F%'
 ORDER BY 4 * (str_col LIKE 'FR10%') +
          3 * (str_col LIKE 'FR1%') +
          2 * (str_col LIKE 'FR%') +
          1 * (str_col LIKE 'F%') DESC,
          CHAR_LENGTH(str_col),
          str_col
```

Output:

```
| STR_COL |
|---------|
|    FR10 |
|    FR12 |
|    FRFF |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baa13/5)** demo

Comment: Mm, it seems to me this elaborate WHERE clause is redundant. str_col LIKE 'F%' already matches all the other options, so the other options are not required and possibly wasteful.